# Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. In API APP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

Error is throwing when it tries to create the Controller.

Error:

> {   "Message": "An error has occurred.",   "ExceptionMessage": "An
>   error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'DeviceController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.InvalidOperationException",   "StackTrace": "   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
>   "InnerException": {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "Type 'OLIT.VehicleSDN.ClientApi.DeviceController' does not have a default
>   constructor",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)"   } }

This is the WebApiConfig:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IDevice, Device>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISettingsRepository, SettingsRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IDeviceRegistryManager, DeviceRegistryManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

 config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

This is the Controller;

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDevice _device;


    public DeviceController(IDevice device)
    {
        _device = device;
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: What you've shown should work. Show where you call the `WebApiConfig` at startup.

Comment: You forgot to register your `DeviceController`. Please remember: always register all root types explicitly in the container (even if your container can construct unregistered concrete types).

Comment: Could you share the code for `Device`?